# Angular Reactive forms transform piped string value back to integer

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular reactive form.  I am using a pipe transform with my `formControlName` on my form.  I subscribe to the value and then change it so that it changes the display:

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
    if(form.value){
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
            value: this.decimalPipe.transform(form.value.toString().replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), '1.0-2', 'en')
        }, { emitEvent: false })
    }
})
```

The issue I am running into now, is that this actually changes my value to a string, so adding `type: number` onto my input in the view is useless.  I have an HTML view and need to bind my data to an input with `formControlName` because they need to be editable, like this:

`<input formControlName="value" />`

How do I actually change this back to an `integer` to pass it off to the server?  I get a 400 error if passing a string where an int is expected.

There are about 20 fields in my DTO that are of type `int`, so there must be a better way than replacing every field with a number right before passing it off to my http call.

Comment: Where does the value changes to string? Are you aware of the simple `+` sign casting string to a number - you can put a `+` sign before your string like `+"SomeNumericString"`

Comment: Yes, I am aware.  But because the value goes through a pipe, it then changes to a string.  The value comes out 1,111,111 for instance.  So adding a + does not change that to a number.  And I need it piped for display purposes in the view.

Comment: and why not using the pipe in the view? is it html template? does showing your value like `<span>{{SomeNumericString | decimalPipe}}</span>` is an option?

Comment: Yes, using html.  I'll edit my answer thanks.  I need to bind the data to `formControlName`.